# How to handle exception if Entity DB file is not found

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm using Entity fw with SQL server compact database.
Problem is, that I can't seem to understand how and where to handle
System.Data.EntityException if database file is not found, 
because when I start my application
a "..has stopped working" window pops up with the following details

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   AVIOB1BUUW4KTDA4Y2PQRQUMWZFODHST
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   5151de5d
Problem Signature 04:   System.Data.SqlServerCe
Problem Signature 05:   4.0.8876.1
Problem Signature 06:   4fcd17f1
Problem Signature 07:   17b
Problem Signature 08:   4ad
Problem Signature 09:   System.Data.EntityException
```

Also, I can't seem to debug the application from VS2012, because of the error it doesn't run, so I had to test it manually by renaming the db file.

**How** and **where** to handle this exception?

Comment: In visual studio, try to enable [breaking on all unhandled exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/038tzxdw(v=vs.80).aspx). This will break debugger when any exception is thrown. Generally, exception for missing db can be thrown when you construct instance of DbContext.

Comment: You don't want to _handle_ this exception. You want to find out why the file is not found, then change your code to find it. If it's not where it's meant to be, then how can you _handle_ the exception?

Comment: for example, if database file is not found in the specified directory, then MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find database file!"); as a visual warning, and exit the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if (!File.Exists(NameAndLocationofDBFile))
{
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Database file does not exist");
     return; // exist application
}
```